# Formatting Amex credit card

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am using below code to format credit card, while user is entering data. My requirement is to format amex credit card in 4 6 5 format and rest in 4 4 4 4 format. problem is amex card formatting is not happening until all the 15 digits are entered. while other validation is happening as soon as user enters 5th charecter. how do i make it happen in case of amex too?

```
if(result.card_type.name == 'amex' )
{
    $(this).val(function(i, v){
        /*   var v = v.replace(/[^\d]/g, '').match(/.{1,4}/g); */
        var v = v.replace(/\b(\d{4})(\d{6})(\d{5})\b/, '$1 $2 $3');
        return v;
    }); 
}
else{
    $(this).val(function(i, v){
        var v = v.replace(/[^\d]/g, '').match(/.{1,4}/g);
        return v ? v.join(' ') : '';
    });  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`var v = v.replace(/\b(\d{4})(\d{6})(\d{5})\b/, '$1 $2 $3');` will match when 4+6+5 digets found

Try this one

```
$(this).val(function(i, v){
  v = v.replace(/\b(\d{4})/, '$1-');
  v = v.replace(/-(\d{6})/, '-$1-');
  return v;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zgpwmmjy/

Comment: This is causing all kinds of strange behavior after entering a valid number.

Comment: When i enter `012345678901234` i'll get `0123-456789-01234`. This code is only for the `result.card_type.name == 'amex'` part of our code.